# What does "snapping at my nethers" mean？

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have recently watched *The Witcher*, and there is a sentence that I don't quite understand,

> He pulls me up by the scruff of my neck, and slays the monster snapping at my nethers.

What does "snapping at my nethers" mean?

Comment: [Nether regions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nether%20parts%2Fregions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*KillingTime* has already given a link to the word *"nethers"*; here is one of the meanings the verb *"snap"*:

> [intransitive] snap (at somebody/something) to try to bite somebody/something
> [(source: Oxford Learner's Dictionary)](http://%5Bintransitive%5D%20snap%20(at%20somebody/something)%20to%20try%20to%20bite%20somebody/something)

So, *"snapping at my nethers"* probably means that wyvern tried to bite the character (Nivellen) at his penis.